# How do I expose MultiValidationBehavior's children in custom control?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I'm creating a custom control for an entry that can be validated.

I did this by creating a ContentView that has a Grid as it's child that contains the entry, error label, etc.

I'd like this to be flexible when it comes to validation, so ideally it would be nice to expose the Entry's MultiValidationBehavior's Children property, or set that property as my control's content property.

As it stands now, I haven't figured out a way to add behaviors to my custom control.

Is this possible?

```
<ContentView x:Class="MPK.UI.Views.Components.FormEntry"
             x:Name="FormEntryControl"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MPK.UI.Converters;assembly=MPK.UI">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:IsValidToEntryBorderConverter x:Key="IsValidToEntryBorderConverter"/>
            <converters:ErrorsToLabelTextConverter x:Key="ErrorsToLabelTextConverter"/>
            <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
        
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="10"
                           HeightRequest="50"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           BackgroundColor="{StaticResource EntryBackgroundColor}"
                           Padding="16,0,16,0">
            <yummy:PancakeView.Behaviors>
                <xct:AnimationBehavior AnimateCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}, Path=ShakeCommand}">
                    <xct:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType>
                        <xct:ShakeAnimation />
                    </xct:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType>
                </xct:AnimationBehavior>
            </yummy:PancakeView.Behaviors>
            <yummy:PancakeView.Border>
                <yummy:Border
                    Color="{Binding IsValid, Source={x:Reference MultiValidationBehavior}, Converter={StaticResource IsValidToEntryBorderConverter}}"
                    Thickness="1" />
            </yummy:PancakeView.Border>
            <Entry x:Name="Entry"
                   Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}"
                   Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}"
                   ReturnType="{Binding ReturnType, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}"
                   ReturnCommand="{Binding ReturnCommand, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}"
                   PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource EntryPlaceholderTextColor}"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   IsPassword="{Binding IsPassword, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}"
                   ClearButtonVisibility="{Binding ClearButtonVisibility, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}">
                <Entry.Effects>
                    <xct:RemoveBorderEffect />
                </Entry.Effects>
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <xct:MultiValidationBehavior x:Name="MultiValidationBehavior" 
                                                 IsValid="{Binding IsValid, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                 Children="{Binding ValidationBehaviors, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}}"/>
                    <!-- Binding children doesn't work here -->
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
        </yummy:PancakeView>
        <xct:Expander Margin="8,4,0,0"
                      AnimationLength="100"
                      IsExpanded="{Binding IsValid, Source={x:Reference FormEntryControl}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}">
            <Label Text="{Binding Errors, Source={x:Reference MultiValidationBehavior}, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsToLabelTextConverter}}"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource ErrorColor}" />
        </xct:Expander>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: What comes to mind is to take a different approach. Add methods to your control that do what you want. E.g. a method that can add a validation behavior. Then anyone that uses the control will have to write "code behind" to call that method. Something like `PancakeView.AddValidation(Behavior behavior) { MultiValidationBehavior.Children.Add(behavior); }`  I haven't tried this, so the code may need to be a bit different than this. If you go down this road, but get stuck, then add to your question the code you tried, and what goes wrong.

Comment: I think you're on to something. But could do it as a bindable property so that it can still be accomplished in xaml?

Comment: I can't picture in my mind how to use a bindable property, because I don't know how another view would ADD to the list (using XAML). Make a test where you write a view that uses this custom control. Get the code a far as you can (with a comment or not-working pseudo-code at the point the new view would try to bind to this view to add a behavior), add that to your question, then add a comment here so I'll be notified that you've made a change.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was much simpler than I expected.

In my control's code behind I needed to add a property that points to the multivalidationbehavior's children property.

```
public IList<ValidationBehavior> ValidationBehaviors => TheMultiValidationBehavior.Children;
```

Using my custom control looks something like this:

```
            <components:FormEntry Placeholder="Name">
                <components:FormEntry.ValidationBehaviors>
                    <xct:TextValidationBehavior MinimumLength="1" xct:MultiValidationBehavior.Error="Min: 1"/>
                </components:FormEntry.ValidationBehaviors>
            </components:FormEntry>
```